# Deserialize BinaryData and mapping to an object

Tags: ios, swift

I have a small project where I have a list with questions (96 questions).
I try to serialize that list of questions into a BinaryData and to save that result in CoreData.
After I want to deserialize that BinaryData from CoreData and to map the values to an object.
The problem is that my serialization I think is working, but the deserialization is not working for some reason.
This line of code is not called when I run the code and I don't know why:

https://github.com/tygruletz/AddTagsForRows/blob/master/PreloadQuestions/Controller/Communication/TTable.swift#L457

To generate a report in CoreData just click Next-> Next-> Finish.

Here is the code for deserialization:

```
func deStreamBin(stream: InputStream, format: EStreamFormat){

        var protocolByte: UInt8 = 0
        var columns: UInt16 = 0
        var rows: UInt32 = 0
        var tableFlag: ETableFlags

        //We should scroll through 0's until we find '1' indicating the start of a table
        while protocolByte != 0x01 {
            protocolByte = deserializeByte(stream: stream)
        }

        // Header
        _ = deserializeUInt32(stream: stream)
        columns = deserializeUInt16(stream: stream)
        rows = deserializeUInt32(stream: stream)
        print("Number of rows in TTable: \(rows)")

        tableFlag = ETableFlags(rawValue: UInt(deserializeUInt16(stream: stream))) ?? ETableFlags.none          // 0x0001 = Exception, 0x002 = Interrupt
        _ = deserializeByte(stream: stream)                                                                     // Flags (0x01 = Meta, 0x02 = Last Row, 0x00 = The rest)

        // Read the Meta Details
        var tMeta: [TMeta] = []

        for _ in 0..<columns {
            guard let type = EMeta(rawValue: deserializeString(stream: stream, length: 1)) else {return}
            var name = ""

            if format == EStreamFormat.bin1 {
                let nameLength = Int(deserializeByte(stream: stream))
                name = deserializeString(stream: stream, length: nameLength)
            }
            else{
                // No names for the bin2
            }
            tMeta.append(TMeta(type: type, name: name))
        }

        self.tMeta = tMeta
        self.flags = tableFlag

        for _ in 0..<rows {
            let row: TRow = TRow(tMeta: tMeta)
            _ = deserializeUInt32(stream: stream)                                                               // Row Number
            _ = deserializeByte(stream: stream)                                                                 // Flags (0x01 = Meta, 0x02 = Last Row, 0x00 = The rest)

            for i in 0..<tMeta.count {

                let m: TMeta = tMeta[i]

                switch m.type {
                // Integer (Int32)
                case EMeta.i:
                    row.cell[i] = TCell(i: Int(deserializeInt32(stream: stream)))
                // Boolean
                case EMeta.b:
                    row.cell[i] = TCell(b: deserializeBoolean(stream: stream))
                // String (length as UInt32, followed by array of chars)
                case EMeta.s:
                    let nLenString = Int(deserializeUInt32(stream: stream))
                    row.cell[i] = TCell(s: deserializeString(stream: stream, length: nLenString))
                // DateTime (BCD Array: YY YY MM DD hh mm ss)
                case EMeta.t:
                    row.cell[i] = TCell(date: deserializeDateTime(stream: stream) ?? Date())
                // Database Bytes (Length as Int32, followed by array of bytes)
                case EMeta.z:
                    let nLenBytes = Int(deserializeUInt32(stream: stream))
                    row.cell[i] = TCell(data: deserializeByteArray(stream: stream, lenght: Int32(nLenBytes)))
                // Double (IEEE 8-byte double)
                case EMeta.d:
                    row.cell[i] = TCell(d: deserializeDouble(stream: stream))
                // Single Byte
                case EMeta.u:
                    row.cell[i] = TCell(b: deserializeByte(stream: stream))
                }
            }
            do {
                try add(row: row)
            } catch{
                print("deStreamBin: Can't add the row in tMeta: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me to deserialize my BinaryData to be able to map the values to an object.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why binary data at all and if so why not use `Data`?

Comment: Hi Joakim. This was the requirement. How can I use the Data instead ? Can you help me please ?